# Use Burp to fuzzy test the hash value (the values after the # in the URL)

Tags: hash, penetration-test, burp-suite

I know its possible to use a tool like Burp to test Cookie/post/get values , but is it possible to use such tool to perform a brute force/dictionary attack (fuzzy test) on the values after # symbol.

I know that the values after the # in a URL are not sent to the server. They are only interpreted by the browser. This makes it more difficult to use tools such as Burp.

Comment: What would you want to achieve? I have never heard of any malicious use of the hash parameter so why do you want to do a (fuzzy) test?

Comment: Pentesterlab 'Web for Pentester I' XSS exercise 9:
https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester

`document.write(location.hash.substring(1));`

"This example is a DOM-based XSS. This page could actually be completely static and still be vulnerable. ... When the page is rendered, the JavaScript code uses the current URL to retrieve the anchor portion of the URL (#...) and dynamically (on the client side) write it inside the page. This can be used to trigger a XSS vulnerability, if you use the payload as part of the URL [maliciously sent]."